# Can a Composite Simpson's Rule be applied in this case?

Tags: calculus, simpsons-rule

I have been given a table with three values of a function at three different points. In my textbook, the Composite Simpson's Rule has a following form:

$I=\frac h6(f_0+4f_1+2f_2+4f_3+...+2f_{2n-2}+4f_{2n-1}+f_{2n})$

Can this formula be used if I do not have any 'even' values?
Can I do the following?
$I=\frac h6(f_0+4f_1+f_{2n})$

Comment: Simpson's rule can only be applied if the nodes are equidistant.

Comment: @Peter could you please explain me what nodes are?

Comment: The nodes are the $x$-values we use and where the function is given. Equidistant simply means that we must have $c-b=b-a$ for nodes $a<b<c$

Comment: well, they are, as the points I am given are as following: $(-1,8)$, $(0,3)$ and $(1,4)$. So the rule can be applied?

Comment: Yes, it can be applied. The result is exact, if the function is a polynomial with degree no more than $3$.